# How to convert string array literal to array list with no quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

Simple scenario but finding difficult to finish off -

my string is -

```
String ipAdd =     "["2.2.2.2","1.1.1.1","6.6.6.6","4.4.4.4"]"
```

I want to have all elements in an array list. How can I do that?

I try pattern matching for IP and all, not working and by using split function, it includes quotes and bracket.

Comment: What do you mean without quotes? 1.1.1.1 is not a valid thing in Java.

Comment: Do you want a string like `"2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1,6.6.6.6,4.4.4.4"`?

Comment: This is already array of strings. What exactly do you want?

Comment: i want a array list with items 2.2.2.2, 1.1.1.1, 6.6.6.6 and so on ... u can say ["abc","abc2","abc3"] to arraylist with abc and abc2 and abc3 as elements

Comment: No, that is a string

Comment: You have four blocks in apostrophes separated by commas. This is not string.

Comment: Please do not use [java-ee] tag as long as you have a question related to JLS and/or problem is reproducible in a plain Java application class with `main()` method. Those are just basic [java].

Comment: ok .. fine .. will take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replaceAll()` (to remove braces) and `split()` (to split based on comma) should work :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String ipAdd = "[\"2.2.2.2\",\"1.1.1.1\",\"6.6.6.6\",\"4.4.4.4\"]";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ipAdd.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(","));
    for (String s : list){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
"2.2.2.2"
"1.1.1.1"
"6.6.6.6"
"4.4.4.4"
```

Comment: yeah, i thought there would be some better option to do it but yes it would suffice. thanks

Answer (score -1):

The following code maybe fulfill your requirement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String st = "[\"2.2.2.2\",\"1.1.1.1\",\"6.6.6.6\",\"4.4.4.4\"]";

    String patternString1 = "(\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    for (String item : list) {
        System.out.println("" + item);
    }
}
```

You can use regular expression with capturing groups to extract the IP from the string. (refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)

Comment: Please explain your answer; dumping code is rarely useful to readers of the question.

Comment: Have tried it but it is pattern dependent, if I give IP ad 1.1.1.1.1.1.1. also it will accept it and send to matcher as 1.1.1.1, i want exact string to be added in the list :(

Comment: you can change the pattern: String patternString1 = "(\\d(\\.\\d)*)";